# WD My Cloud Ex4 Phpmyadmin login

Tags: authentication, cloud

I bought WD My Cloud EX4 some weeks ago.
I was interested in installing PhpMyAdmin but whenever i do that i can't login!

I tried "root" and no password and it says i can't use an empty password.
I tried mostly all combination with and without password

- root -nopassword-
- root root
- admin admin
- admin -nopassword-
- wdmycloudex4 admin user and password

So here's the question, how can i login or at least change password?

Thanks,
Luca

Comment: Just to be sure: Is it your MySQL root password, or your server root password that you are asking for?
If you have your server root password, you can easily reset the MySQL root password.

Answer (score 5):

On my EX4 with the current firmware (1.05.30), admin/admin worked.

But yeah, if you change anything, you void your warranty, so be careful.

Answer (score 0):

Try user root and password `welc0me`

This was posted by a user on the WD community.

I haven't tried it, as WD warns that this will void the warranty.